# django rest framework user prefix in serializers

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

models.py

```
address_choices = (("home":"Home"),("shop", "Shop"))
    class Address(models.Model):
       address_type = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=address_choices)
       location = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

forms.py

```
class AddressForm(forms.ModelForm):

   class Meta:
      model = Address


views.py


home_address = AddressForm(prefix="shop")
shop_address = AddressForm(prefix="home")
```

can i use prefix in serializers just like that i used in forms above

serializers.py

```
class AddressSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

      class Meta:
         model = Address
```

views.py

```
home_serializer = AddressSerializers(prefix="home")
shop_serializer = AddressSerializers(prefix="shop")
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have the current model `Address` it's enough to have one serializer for that. You can specify `{'address_type': 'home'}` or `{'address_type': 'shop'}` when using that. If you want to have multiple addresses (bulk creation) you should use a [ListSerializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#listserializer) or the `many=True` parameter if you used it inside other related serializer.

Comment: is there any way to do this

Comment: Have a look at this [django rest framework bulk](https://github.com/miki725/django-rest-framework-bulk)

Comment: @could you please look this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45319469/django-rest-framwork-iterate-throug-fields-in-model-serializer