# django rest framwork iterate throug fields in model serializer

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

i want to iterate through the fields in ModelSerializer and want to make those field required . this not working . how can i do that. Somebody please help me.

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Customer

        fields = ("email", "phone_no", "full_name", "landline_no")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].required = True
            self.fields[field].allow_blank = False
```

Comment: Have you tried `super(CustomerSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)` ??

Comment: @zaidfazil it is python 3. will it work

Comment: calling `super()` like that is the recommended way. Do give it a try!.. I have tried the same in my machine and it works fine. Also, what is that you meant by `not working`, is there any error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the extra args in Meta class for a ModelSerializer, like this:

```
class Meta:
    model = Customer

    fields = ("email", "phone_no", "full_name", "landline_no")
    extra_kwargs = {'email': {'required': True, 'allow_blank': False}}
```

If you need this for all the fields, then you should reconsider your fields inside the `Customer` model. You can add `blank=False` and/or `null=False`. Rest framework takes that information into consideration when creating a ModelSerializer